# Obter conteúdo do e-mail

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu estou usando o seguinte:

```
import imaplib
import email

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
m.login("myemail","mypass")
m.select("Inbox")

result, data = m.uid('search', None, "ALL") # search all email and return uids
if result == 'OK':
    for num in data[0].split():
        result, data = m.uid('fetch', num, '(RFC822)')
        if result == 'OK':
            email_message = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])    # raw email text including headers
            print 'From:' + email_message['subject'] 

m.close()
m.logout()
```

Só consigo obter o Assunto do e-mail, e eu quero o conteúdo da mensagem.
Quais são os valores além de subject e from?

**Usando python 2.7**

Answer (score -1):

Olá!

Acredito que esse post possa te auxiliar nessa questão amigo:

[Utilizacação do imaplib(inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230037/how-to-fetch-an-email-body-using-imaplib-in-python)
Como sugestão deixo a biblioteca [IMAPClient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMAPClient/) que eu acho muito mais simples de se trabalhar. Descrição deles:

> Easy-to-use, Pythonic and complete IMAP client library.